# Algebra Invariants of Schubert Calculus

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, grassmannians, flag-varieties, schubert-calculus

For the Grassmannian Gr[N,k] of $k$-planes in $\mathbb{C}^N$, the cohomology ring $H^*(Gr[N,k])$ is a much studied object in an area called Schubert calculus. As a complex algebra, $H^*(Gr[N,k])$ is finite dimensional. These algebras are not distinguished by their dimension (see the comment below). Do there exists other invariants of finite dimensional algebras that distinguish these rings? For example, are they distinguished by their Hochschild (co)homology groups?

Comment: Are you asking about the dimension as a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space?  For every pair $(k,N)$ with $4\leq 2k \leq N$, define $\ell$ to be $\text{dim}_{\mathbb{C}} H^*(\text{Grass}(k,\mathbb{C}^N);\mathbb{C})$.  Then $X=\text{Grass}(1,\mathbb{C}^\ell)$ also has $\text{dim}_{\mathbb{C}}H^*(X;\mathbb{C})$ equal to $\ell$.

Comment: Yes, dimension as a complex vector space. So I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: I think the Betti numbers should be a complete invariant. So although it is not enough to calculate the dimension of $H^*(Gr)$, it should be enough to calculate the dimension of each graded piece.

Comment: @Oliver. Definitely the Betti numbers reconstruct $k$ and $N$.  As above, assume that $2k\leq N$.  Then the Betti number $b_{2r}$ equals the partition function $P(r)$ for $r\leq k$, but $b_{2k+2}$ does not equal the partition number.  So that uniquely determines $k$.  Also the socle degree is when $2r=2k(N-k)$.  So the data of $k$ together with the socle degree uniquely determines $N$.

Comment: @JasonStarr That's more or less what I was thinking, although I hadn't checked the details. It's not clear to me if this resolves the OP's question or not.